# Boolean and == vs =

Tags: java, boolean

The language is Java.
Given this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean b1 = true;
    Boolean b2 = true;
    int i1 = 1;

    if (b1 = true) //line 5
    if (b1 == true}  // line 6
```

I understand that `b1 == true` is a equivalent test , which will give the result : true OR false. However, with `b1 = true` , which to my understanding is a declaration, which should return nothing but in this case : `b1 = true` returns true, exactly the same as `==` test?

Can you explain why? Thanks!

Comment: `b1 = true` is an assignment not declaration. `Boolean b1;` is a declaration.

Comment: Are you sure it is a compilation **error**? Because such things(variable not used) are shown as **warnings** in _eclipse_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`if (identifier = literal)` evaluates to:

```
identifier = literal;  
if (identifier)
```

first you assign the literal to the identifier. then you test it post assignment

Comment: Wow, now I understand, thank you very much! That is the reason why the compiler said *"The value of the local variable b1 is not used"* . I'm reading the book of SCJP but they didn't mention the knowledge you give me. Is that belonged to a higher level than SCJP?

Comment: @user1525788 actually I dont even know Java that well, I mainly use C/C++, but this rule applies to most C-family languages.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
b1 = true;
```

`true` is assigned to b1.

When you write

```
if(b1 = true)
```

first the assignation is done and then the expression is evaluated and the expression evaluates to value of `b1` i.e. `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason both return true is simply because both expressions are true.

b1 = true is an assignment --> You tell java that b1 is true and when it evaluates it becomes true because here you simply say b1 is true.

b1 == true is a condition --> This is the line that makes some sense because you are now checking if [value of] b1 equals to true and this will evaluate to true or false depending on if b1 is true. Note that you could just write b1 because it's already a boolean (true or false).

I don't think you have realized it but you are using the object-type Boolean and not the primitive type boolean. You should stick to the one with a lowercase b if you don't really know the diffrence between object-based types and primtive types in Java.

btw I didn't know that Java allowed assignment to be used as a expression.