# Boolean always returning false

Tags: java, boolean, minecraft, bukkit

I'm new to java and i'm trying to make a minecraft plugin. I want a debug mode so I decided to create a boolean that I can switch with a command, but whatever I do it returns false except the p.sendMessage at the end that always says the debug message.Here's my code:

```
package fr.davidp027.itemlogger;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
    public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

 public static Boolean debug = false;

 public void onEnable() {
  PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
  pm.registerEvents(this, this);
 }

 public void onDiasble() {

 }

 public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, 
   Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
  //Player player = (Player) sender;
  if (cmd.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("lping")) {
   sender.sendMessage("Command Working :D");
  } else if (cmd.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("ildebug")) {
   if (Main.debug = false) {
    sender.sendMessage("Debug mode turned ON. Type command again to disable.");
    Main.debug = true;
   } else if (Main.debug = true) {
    sender.sendMessage("Debug mode turned OFF. Type command again to enable.");
    Main.debug = false;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 @EventHandler
 public void Blockplace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
  Player p = e.getPlayer();
  Material b = e.getBlock().getType();
  Location l = e.getBlock().getLocation();
  if (Main.debug = true) {
   p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You placed the following block: " + ChatColor.GOLD + b + 
     ChatColor.RED + " at the following location" + ChatColor.GOLD + " X: " + l.getBlockX() + " Y: " + 
     l.getBlockY() + " Z: " + l.getBlockZ() + ChatColor.RED + " and your name is: " + ChatColor.GOLD + p.getDisplayName());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Prefer `boolean` to `Boolean`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boolean and == vs =](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399205/boolean-and-vs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
if(Main.debug = false){
```

Performs an assignment, not a test. You need

```
if(Main.debug == false){
```

or just

```
if (!Main.debug){
```

Also,

```
else if(Main.debug = true)
```

should be

```
else if(Main.debug == true)
```

or

```
else if(Main.debug)
```

or (in your case)

```
else
```

Comment: Works, thanks for the quick anwser. I'll accept it once I can I need to wait 7 mins before.

Answer (score 2):

`if(Main.debug = false){` is basically assigning `false` to `Main.debug` and then evaluating the value, which is false, so it goes to the next condition....

It should be something more like...

```
if(!Main.debug){
    sender.sendMessage("Debug mode turned ON. Type command again to disable.");
    Main.debug = true;
} else { // Can't be anything else...
    sender.sendMessage("Debug mode turned OFF. Type command again to enable.");
    Main.debug = false;
}
```

And, last but not least, the method only ever returns false...

```
return false;
```

So, I don't know what you're actually expecting...

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> **The Equality and Relational Operators**
>
> The equality and relational operators determine if one operand is
>   greater than, less than, equal to, or not equal to another operand.
>   The majority of these operators will probably look familiar to you as
>   well. **Keep in mind that you must use "==", not "=", when testing if
>   two primitive values are equal.**
>
> ==      equal to
>    !=      not equal to
>    >       greater than
>    >=      greater than or equal to
>    <       less than
>    <=      less than or equal to

In your code you are using the assignment operator `=`:

```
if(Main.debug = false){
```

You should be using the equality operator `==`:

```
if(Main.debug == false){
```

and

```
} else if(Main.debug == true) {
```

In addition, as debug is a Boolean (as Code-Apprentice pointed out), you can simplify your code as well:

```
if(!Main.debug){ // debug is false
```

and

```
} else { // debug is true
```

Comment: Better yet, remove the comparison all together since `debug` is already a `Boolean` value.